# Convert UUID to String for insert in mongodb

Tags: string, mongodb, shell, uuid, robo3t

Upon trying the following code:

```
db.getCollection('col').find({}).forEach(function(doc){
            var id = new UUID().toString(); // this doesn't work, neither does 'var id = new UUID();'
            db.getCollection('pubCol')
                .update({
                    "uuid" : id,
                    "deleted" : false
                    }
            , {upsert: true});
         });
```

I end up getting the following results respectively

```
"uuid" : "UUID(\"4554a991-2b7f-4464-b871-5f4e91332630\")"
"uuid" : UUID("4554a991-2b7f-4464-b871-5f4e91332630")
```

But I am looking for

```
"uuid" : "4554a991-2b7f-4464-b871-5f4e91332630"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UUID().hex()` returns the string you are after but without hyphens.

You can split it manually, e.g. with regexp:

```
UUID().hex().match(/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$/).slice(1,6).join('-')
```

Comment: This would work to what I can test out. But the regex part makes it complicated though.

Comment: How about `.toString().substring(...)`?

Comment: It will do the trick but it's not the intended use of toString(). UUID has 3 methods: base64, hex, and toString. The later returns JS representation. You want the hex one. The regexp is a workaround for the lack of hyphens. I would rather raise a feature request to add an optional "separator" parameter to the hex method.